# How to run a script in nodeserver every hour?

Tags: node.js, cron, meanjs

I have a mean.js project, with this structure in the app (where the server files are):

```
-app
 --controllers
 --models
 --docs
 --logs
 --routes
 --tests
 --views
 bower.json
 Gruntfile.js
 package.json
 README.md
```

I want to do a "cron job" every hour or so on my mongodb.

I ran into this:

```
https://github.com/scripting/noderunner
```

Where should i place it and how do i use it let's say for the sake of example,
to do console.log of "hello world" every 1 hour?

Comment: Why don't just use cron on your server? http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/time.html#cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you must install cron to your os, after this you must set cron job, for do this you must write "crontab -e" in console and set job, somthing like this:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/project/bin/your_script.js
```

Important! You must add hashbang(#!/usr/bin/env node
) to first line in you script and set permissions. Good luck.